# How to water level deconvolve a noisy signal if i have a zeros and poles file?

Tags: noise, deconvolution, poles-zeros

Thanks for your time and help!

I am working with Apollo project passive seismic experiment (PSE) data, and I have a large set of seismic records (on digital counts) and the corresponding file of poles and zeros.

I need to deconvolve these registers to obtain calibrated seismograms on SI units.

I have read that this can be accomplished with a water-level deconvolution of 10% but I am not sure of how can make this.

I ask for some orientation and if possible bibliographical references

I am working in MatLab

Comment: Hi Oscar and welcome to DSP.SE! I may help give further details if you link what you have read, assuming it is available online. From what you wrote it sounds like there is a correlation of seismic data to water levels and you are trying to normalize that out perhaps-- not clear to me but perhaps others with experience with seismic data analysis will recognize what you are trying to do and why.

Comment: Hello @DanBoschen, Thanks for your interest. The Water-Level refers to a type of regularized convolution to solve stability problems introduced for noise on the signal after deconvolution. The document I have is The 1979 Ph.D. Thesis of Peter Horvath [link](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19800004725.pdf), the chapter 2 is dedicated to the deconvolution with Water-Level Method

Comment: Interesting- is it referring to actual water level data or is that an analogy?

Comment: @DanBoschen There is no water involved. Please takes a look at [link](http://www.ees.nmt.edu/outside/courses/GEOP505/Docs/deconv.pdf). There the authors expose Water-Level deconvolution but with an algorithm different from Horvath. My main difficulty is finding the correct frequency bins! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had no idea this was called water level deconvolution, but it appears to be what Wertheim (at the old Bell Labs) was doing in 1975: G.K. Wertheim, Deconvolution and Smoothing: Applications in ESCA, J. Electron Spectroscopy and Related Phenomena, 6 (1975) 239-251. I do not have an online link to this paper, just an old scanned copy. Wertheim seems to be using a 10% "water level". Best of success with your project/research!

Comment: Thanks @ED V. I going to search and review that paper